# Transferring ArrayList <String> elements to a two-dimensional array String

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to easily create a table and load a text file into it. I came up with the constructor `JTable (Object [] [] rowData, Object [] columnNames)`. So I will load the file into the arraylist and then create a two-dimensional array based on it and from two-dimensional i will create another one-dimensional array. Can it be done in a simpler way and if so, how?

```
Scanner s;
s=new

Scanner((new File("plik.txt")));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(s.hasNextLine()){
    list.add(s.next());
}

JFrame f;
f = new JFrame();
String[][] data = new String[list.size()][3];

for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){

    String column[ i]=data[0][i];

    JTable jt = new JTable(data, column);

    jt.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);

    f.add(sp);
    f.setSize(300, 400);
}
```

The column names correspond to the names in the first row of each column.In addition, the elements in the two-dimensional array are to be distinguished by a tab character (i.e. several spaces),ie a line in the text file "one one one   two two two" in the two-dimensional table "one one one" will be one element / column in the table and "two two two" will be the next element / column.

Comment: Why the detours? I think you want to research table **models**, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data for example.

Comment: You are creating three JTables.  Was that your intent?